# Can I get LaTeX output with explicitly printed multiplication signs in Math.NET?

Tags: latex, math.net

I'm using SymbolicExpression.ToLaTeX to generate LaTeX output based on my expression.

Is it possible to add some option to get it to print the following:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

Comment: don't abuse math mode for hole words - this messes up the kerning

Comment: It would seem that when at least one of the terms of a product is a full word, we always have to use a clearer notation.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I see. I have very little experience with LaTeX. I started using Math.NET recently and found out there is such a thing as math mode from your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this was not supported. However, I've addressed this just now, so starting from the next release (newer than 0.21) this will be formatted as:

```
\mathrm{height} \cdot \mathrm{weight}
```

[image]

Comment: In case you are loading `amsmath`, it might be better to use `\text{...}`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/is-there-a-preference-of-when-to-use-text-and-mathrm

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix and response!

Comment: While we are on the subject. I have some symbol names containing underscore. Resulting in this: {Q8_{3_{3}}}. Is there a way to make anything in symbol names be considered plain text?

Comment: This is currently a convention, by design. Can you open an issue in the repo to discuss what we can do? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/issues/86

Answer (score 1):

Use `\cdot`

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
(...)
height $\cdot$ weight
```

and if you really want to put the words in math mode too, I'd recommend the following:

```
$$\textrm{height} \cdot \textrm{weight}$$
```

where `\textrm` makes text looks 'normal' (or `\textit` for italics)

#### Tip for symbol

If you don't know how to get a specific symbol in Tex, you can draw it in Detexify and it gives you the best matches (and tells in which packages they're defined): https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html. For instance:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted because it is essentially how this shall be addressed within Math.NET Symbolics (which this question was really about). Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use `$$...$$` in latex, that's the syntax for plain tex, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to. For the inline example, the spacing around the dot will be wrong.

Comment: @ChristophRüegg Is there a timeframe for this update? I just noticed [this issue](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/issues/79) on the GitHub repo.

Comment: I've already addressed it in master. With this change it now renders as `\mathrm{height} \cdot \mathrm{weight}`

Comment: Not really answering my question about MathNet. But thanks for the mini LaTeX-tutorial :)